# Native registration to Azure hub always crashes the first time the app is launched

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, azure-mobile-services

I've made a iOS 7.0 app that use push-notifications and the Azure Mobile services framework. All is good, but I've seen that when I clear my app (e.g., remove it from my phone to force a "first launch" use-case), the app crashes from what I assume is a bug/crash within the Azure framework?

Basically, I'm running the following code-snippet;

```
//Proceed and register
SBNotificationHub* hub = [[SBNotificationHub alloc] initWithConnectionString:notificationConnectionString
                                                          notificationHubPath:notificationHub];

DDLogInfo(@"Hub object = %@", hub);

//Register with native hub...
NSError* error = nil;

if (![hub registerNativeWithDeviceToken:deviceToken tags:nil error:&error])
{
    //False
    DDLogInfo(@"Failed to register with native hub...");
    if (error)
        DDLogError(@"Found error; %@", error.localizedDescription);
}
```

... and when `registerNativeWithDeviceToken:` is executed, my app crashes with the following exception;

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil'
```

Enabling breakpoint exceptions show the following trace, indicating that it's the *SBLocalStorage* class, part of the Azure framework, that try to put *nil* in a NSDictionary;

- Thread 4, Queue : NSManagedObjectContext Queue
- #0    0x3bc7e1f0 in __pthread_kill ()
- #9    0x30e6e1be in -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] ()
- #10   0x0022afa8 in -[SBLocalStorage updateWithRegistrationName:registration:] at /Users/admin/Desktop/Main/enlist/WindowsAzureMessaging/WindowsAzureMessaging/Helpers/SBLocalStorage.m:89
- #11   0x0022ae4c in -[SBLocalStorage updateWithRegistration:] at /Users/admin/Desktop/Main/enlist/WindowsAzureMessaging/WindowsAzureMessaging/Helpers/SBLocalStorage.m:70
- #12   0x00227d76 in -[SBNotificationHub retrieveAllRegistrationsWithDeviceToken:error:] at /Users/admin/Desktop/Main/enlist/WindowsAzureMessaging/WindowsAzureMessaging/SBNotificationHub.m:700
- #13   0x00227202 in -[SBNotificationHub registerNativeWithDeviceToken:tags:error:] at /Users/admin/Desktop/Main/enlist/WindowsAzureMessaging/WindowsAzureMessaging/SBNotificationHub.m:458
- #14   0x000b6788 in -[BackendCommunicator **registerPushNotificationsForDeviceToken:**] at /Users/markus/Xcode/MyApp/myApp/BackendCommunicator.m:1632

But, regardless, has anyone else seen this? And moreover, why does it work all consecutive launches, BUT NOT the first?

Best,
/Markus

Comment: I get almost exactly the same, periodically, on test builds. If we manually disable notifications for the App, it runs fine, since this code isn't executed. @efimovandr - is the recommendation to upgrade to 2.0 https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/CHANGELOG.ios.md#sdk-downloads

Comment: Still seeing this, even with the latest version (2.0) of azure. Without manually disabling notifications for the app via OS settings, the app is unusable because we sync with azure on startup (with notifications already authorized for this device). I've verified that the device ID isn't nil on sync with the hub

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the issue you described, but for me SDK works OK at this scenario. However I found and fixed serious bug.

Latest version is available on Git Hub, I've also uploaded ready-to-use binaries for your convenience: https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs/tree/master/iOS/bin.

So I would suggest you to try if it works after last fixes.

Comment: Does v2.0 have this fix, and better handling of nil dictionary keys? https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/CHANGELOG.ios.md#sdk-downloads